# How I can use songs(mp3) in my web app using song link directly with audio tag

Tags: html, web, audio, html5-audio, audio-player

I want to use mp3 songs in my app that way

```
<audio class="audio" src="http://link/address/song_name.mp3"></audio>
```

How to do it or any alternative way

Comment: This should work, as long as the mp3 can be accessed. Please check in the developer tools of your browser if it can load the file, or if that's prohibited by a same-origin policy. If the file is not hosted on the same domain as the html/website, consult the [crossorigin docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin).

Comment: **(1)** _"How to do it"_ you can try following some online tutorial, here is [testable code from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio). **(2)** Are you making an app (stored on device along with MP3 files) or an online website (where your MP3 files are on same server as the html files)? Not clear if your question is "How to play" or "Where to store" MP3s online?